# Detect substring within a string while not considering part of the substring

Tags: r, string-matching, stringr

I'm trying to check whether string B is contained by string A and this is what I tried:

```
library(stringr)
string_a <- "something else free/1a2b a bird yes"
string_b <- "free/xxxx a bird"
str_detect(string_a, string_b)
```

I would expect a match (TRUE) since I wouldn't like to consider part of string_b followed by the "/" and before a white space, which is why I put "/xxxx".

In a way the "/xxxx" should represent match any string or number possible in these places. Is there maybe another notation to ignore parts of string when matching like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in regex you can use `.*` to match zero or more characters.

```
library(stringr)
string_a <- "something else free/1a2b a bird yes"
string_b <- "free/xxxx a bird"
string_c <- "free/.*a bird"

str_detect(string_a, string_c)
#[1] TRUE
```

If you cannot change `string_b` at source, you may use `str_replace_all` or `gsub` to replace `xxxx` with `'.*'`.

```
str_detect(string_a, str_replace_all(string_b, 'x+', '.*'))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: your answer is complete, but in order to increase my knowledge about string matching would you know any good sources to learn more about this specific subject ?

Comment: I have learned mostly through examples on stack overflow. You may refer https://www.regular-expressions.info/ but I haven't used it myself.